# AVAudioRecorder normalize volume

Tags: iphone, volume, avaudiorecorder, normalize

I've got an app that records audio.  I'm wondering how I can increase the gain.  is there a way to normalize the audio or amplify it somehow?

thanks,
howie

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I found a solution.  According to the documentation the AVAudioPlayer volume can be between 0.0 and 1.0.  Apparently it can be set to a value greater than 1.0.  By increasing the volume I was able to achieve the same desired result.  While it's not normalized, the gain is increased.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;                
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,          
                             sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

It will play your sound in Speaker mode.